# how to iterate through an Icollection In MVC3 nhibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, nhibernate, drop-down-menu

i am developing an application in mvc3.

I have two dropdowns and on the basis of value selected in first dropdown the second dropdown is populated.
The first dropdown is Course and on the basis of course selected the second dropdown populates the states where the course is available.

Foreg.if the course is 'MCA' the states should be Maharashtra,rajasthan and so-on.
For this i have written an ajax function which is working fine.
But the problem is i am not able to fetch multiple states at a time that is i can fetch only One state at a time.

I have written the following Code to fetch the state name:

HobbyHomeAdress Table contains ProvincialStateID which i fetch through some other method.
Then i compare that value with the value in ProvincialStateID in ProvincialState Table and fetch the data of that table but with it gives me the last record only.

```
 public ICollection<ProvincialState> FetchStateByStateid(ICollection<HobbyHomeAddress> hobbyhomeaddresslist)
    {
        log.Debug("Start");
        ISession session = DataAccessLayerHelper.OpenWriterSession();
        ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
        ICollection<ProvincialState> provincialstate = null;
        try
        {
            foreach (var state in hobbyhomeaddresslist)
            {
                provincialstate = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(ProvincialState))
                                .Add(Expression.Eq("ProvincialStateID", state.ProvincialState.ProvincialStateID))
                                .List<ProvincialState>();
            }
            transaction.Commit();

        }
        catch (SessionException ex)
        {
            if (transaction != null && transaction.IsActive)
                transaction.Rollback();

            log.Error(ex);
            provincialstate = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (transaction != null)
                transaction.Dispose();

            if (session != null && session.IsConnected)
                session.Close();

            log.Debug("End");
        }
        return provincialstate;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are recreating the provincialstate collection for each state in hobbyhomeaddresslist. So you end up with a collection with a single entry, usually the last one. Instead you should create the collection upfront and after retrieving an item, just add it to that collection.

...snip

```
    ...
    List<ProvincialState> provincialstate = new List<ProvincialState>();
    try
    {
        foreach (var state in hobbyhomeaddresslist)
        {

            var list = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(ProvincialState))
                            .Add(Expression.Eq("ProvincialStateID",       state.ProvincialState.ProvincialStateID))
                            .List<ProvincialState>();
            provincialstate.AddRange(list);
        }
        transaction.Commit();

    }
    ...
```

Update: single query using a Disjunction.

```
    IList<ProvincialState> provincialstate = null;
    Disjunction dj = new Disjunction();    
    try
    {
        foreach (var state in hobbyhomeaddresslist)
        {
            dj.Add(Expression.Eq("ProvincialStateID",       state.ProvincialState.ProvincialStateID));
        }
        provincialstate = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(ProvincialState))
                       .Add(dj)
                       .List<ProvincialState>();

        transaction.Commit();

    }
```

if you look at the generated SQL, you should now see a single select with several where clauses instead of several selects with a single where clause.

Comment: thanx 4 reply i understood ur explanation but i dont get any function as 'AddRange()' doi have to add some thing for it??

Comment: you do realise this is asking for trouble with an n+1 query

Comment: @user1274646: did you change the definition of provincialstate from ICollection<> to List<>? ICollection doesn't have AddRange, List has. And List implements ICollection, so you can return the List as an ICollection.

Comment: @GarlandGreene yes i changed it...IList<ProvincialState> provincialstate = new List<ProvincialState>();
but still wen i write provincialstate.AddRange(list) it does not recognise it.
All i get is only Add() can i use that in place of this???

Comment: not IList<>, List<>. But as you currently only load one item at a time, you could also use Add() to add that single item. You could also load all items at once, using several EqExpression in a Disjunction (NHibernate Criteria API equivalent of an OR). That way you would get a single collection and only a single select. That would also circumvent the problem Baz1nga mentioned.

Comment: @GarlandGreene hey thanx a lot..and yes indeed it was a silly mistake but in the mean time i tried Add also and that too is working fine but it may give me the problem wat Baz1nga said so can u give me the exact query to fetch using NHibernate Criteria API equivalent of an OR what u suggested me in the previous comment..

Comment: i updated my answer to include an example using a Disjunction.