# foreach through ICollection issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I had a look at this but too complicated for what I want to achieve:
[how to iterate through an Icollection In MVC3 nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136094/how-to-iterate-through-an-icollection-in-mvc3-nhibernate)

I have in my controller:

```
   public ActionResult UserDetails(int id)
{
  var user = ZincService.GetUserForId(id);
  if (user == null || user.Customer.CustomerId != CurrentCustomer.CustomerId)
    return DataNotFound();

  ManageUserViewModel viewModel = new ManageUserViewModel();
  ScormModule scormModule = new ScormModule();

  viewModel.User = user;
  viewModel.IsLockedOut = MembershipService.IsUserLocked(user.Email);
  viewModel.IsActivated = user.DateTimeActivated.HasValue && MembershipService.IsUserApproved(user.Email);
  viewModel.IsArchived = user.IsArchived;
  viewModel.TrainingModulesForUser = user.UserScormModules;
  foreach (int moduleId in user.UserScormModules)
  {
    var name = scormModule.GetScormModuleTitle(moduleId);
    viewModel.TrainingModuleName.Add(name);
  }

  return View(viewModel);
}
```

then ManageUserViewModel:

```
public class ManageUserViewModel
{
 public Entities.User User { get; set; }
 public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
 public bool IsActivated { get; set; }
 public bool IsArchived { get; set; }\
 public ICollection<Entities.Scorm.UserScormModule> TrainingModulesForUser { get; set; }
 public List<string> TrainingModuleName { get; set; }
}
```

and Entities.User:

```
private ICollection<Entities.Scorm.UserScormModule> _userScormModules;
public virtual ICollection<Entities.Scorm.UserScormModule> UserScormModules
{
  get
  {
    if (_userScormModules == null)
      _userScormModules = new List<Entities.Scorm.UserScormModule>();
    return _userScormModules;
  }
  set
  {
    _userScormModules = value;
  }
}
```

and Entities.Scorm.UserScormModule:

```
 public class UserScormModule
 {
   public virtual int UserScormModuleId { get; set; }
   public virtual int Users_UserId { get; set; }
   public virtual int TrainingModuleArtifactScormModules_TrainingModuleArtifactId { get; set; }
   public virtual TrainingModuleArtifactScormModule TrainingModuleArtifactScormModule { get; set; }
   public virtual User User { get; set; }
 }
```

How can I foreach through `(int moduleId in user.UserScormModules)` so I can get the `name` of the module instead of the `id`. I want to pass the names to my view

```
var name = scormModule.GetScormModuleTitle(moduleId);
viewModel.TrainingModuleName.Add(name);
```

Comment: i think i got it, i changed code to: foreach (var row in user.UserScormModules)
      {
        int moduleId = row.UserScormModuleId;
        var name = scormModule.GetScormModuleTitle(moduleId);
        viewModel.TrainingModuleName.Add(name);
      }

Comment: Please convert this to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think i got it, i changed code to:

```
foreach (var row in user.UserScormModules)
{ 
   int moduleId = row.UserScormModuleId;
   var name = scormModule.GetScormModuleTitle(moduleId);    
   viewModel.TrainingModuleName.Add(name); 
 }
```